# enum method fired when object should be

Tags: c#-3.0

I a sample C# console application to display a bug I am experiencing:

```
class Program
{
    public enum Days { Sat = 1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddWhere("a", DateTime.Now);
        AddWhere("a", 0);
        AddWhere("a", 2);
        AddWhere("a", 3);
        AddWhere("a", "4");
        AddWhere("a", Days.Sun);
        AddWhere("a", Days.Fri);
        AddWhere("a", 1);
        AddWhere("a", (int)Days.Sat);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void AddWhere(string columnName, Days cd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enum fired");
    }


    public static void AddWhere(string columnName, object Val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("object fired");
    }
}
```

the output I get is this:

```
object fired
enum fired
object fired
object fired
object fired
enum fired
enum fired
object fired
object fired
```

Why does the enum method fire when 0 is passed in?

Comment: To piggy-back on what JaredPar said, enums are not limiters they are just specifiers. You can pass any valid int into an enum, it just won't have a corresponding identifier to go along with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The special case of 0 is covered in section 1.10 of the C# language specification.

> In order for the default value of an enum type to be easily available, the literal 0 implicitly converts to any enum type

This implicit conversion is causing overload resolution to pick the enum overload over the `object` one.

Comment: @Chris, or just add an int overload and directly forward it to the object one.

Comment: @Chris - Testing for a value is unnecessary, because the method overload is selected at compile time based on the type of the variable, not the value. This problem should only manifest itself with a literal zero, which may be cast to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 2):

JaredPar answered the question. I will add that the work-around is to cast the 0 as the exact type of the desired method overload.

```
AddWhere("a", (object)0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because enums are stored by default as integers and when the compiler tries to resolve the best method overload it decides that `AddWhere(string columnName, Days cd)` is a better match.

Answer (score 0):

Enum fired because 0 is an **int** and the **enum** underlying type is int. **0** is implicitly converted to enum (at compile time) as this conversion is defined by the language.

```
int a = 123;
long b = a;         // implicit conversion from int to long
int c = (int) b;   // explicit conversion from long to int
```

**Some conversions are defined by the language**

**Source**: msdn.microsoft.com

Comment: If that were the reason then all of the cases where another integral constant would also choose the Enum overload and output clearly indicates otherwise.

Comment: 0 is implicitly converted to enum and this behaviour is by desgin.